# Python : How to Generate positive number with a given standard deviation and mean within 0-1?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, numpy-ndarray

I want to generate a list (or array) of all positive numbers, and all the numbers need to be within 0-1.

I've seen one code,
`numpy.random.normal([mean], [standard deviation], [array size])`.
But it generate both positive an negative numbers.

Any other codes/formula that can solve it?

---

Based on the below codes provided by Cardstdani, I found that
`np.random.normal([mean], [STD], [sample size])`, the mean value would be probably incorrect after checking it. For example, if mean = 1.13, STD = 0.339 and size = 4.

Comment: do you want a uniform distribution instead? really you should consult some educational material on statistics/stochastics, to learn about different distributions and what standard deviation is to be expected given a particular distribution's parameters. example: you could use a **uniform distribution**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution where the variance is ((b-a)^2/12), hence standard deviation is the square root of that -- if you need the entire range of 0..1 to be used, but with a particular stddev, you need to ***shape your own distribution***

Comment: try this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Also, I will try on that site.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute value function `np.abs()` and `mod()` to apply modulo operator with the max value that you want:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.mod(np.abs(np.random.normal([0.5], [1], [2])), 1))
```

**Output:**

```
[0.58674917 0.28187618]
```

Comment: Yes, this can all be positive! But I need the number within a range.

Comment: @megan I added the `mod()` function to introduce an  upper limit. After that you can use addition to get any range

Comment: Hey, thanks. But it seems a little bit strange that I found the output didn't match the average. I mean, (0.58674917+0.28187618)/2 is not equal 0.5

Comment: By the way, is it possible to set the lower limit?

Comment: @megan Yes, by default it's set to zero but you can offset it by addition

Comment: Hmmmm, how to set it?

Comment: @megan If you want a range between (-3, 3) you can create a range from (0, 6) and subtract 3

Comment: Now, I feel strange about this ```np.random.normal()``` now. Neither the mean nor the STD is incorrect after checking it.